What type of optical sensor can measure the displacement similar to an optical mouse?
Imagine there is a simple 2-wheel bogie on a rail:

Bogey has:

Rubber wheels with the same profile as the rail for a "perfect" grip
Low rail clearance. Bottom of the battery (yellow) is about 1cm away from the checkered rail surface
Powered by a simple, non-encoding electric motor that is controlled by MCU+ESC unit.
Desired low max speed (1m/s) but rapid acceleration/braking.

The bogey will need to move along the track and make stops at predetermined points. Since the motor is non-encoding, there is no way to know where the bogie is at any given moment  by using odometry data.
Since the bogey has a relatively low rail clearance, an optical sensor was proposed to be mounted on the underside of the battery:

Ideally this sensor would function similar to the optical mouse: imaging the rail bottom and providing the displacement value of the bogie as it moves.

Aside from the optical sensors used in mice, are there any other options? Any devices that can provide the x-displacement from just "observing" the surface moving underneath?

Generally this class of devices is called an "optical encoder". They're pretty widely used on motors, CNCs and similar positioning equipment so you can probably find something although offhand I can't recommend anything specific.

@user1850479 I used to work with optical encoders, and IIRC this denomination would also refer to the quadrature RPM encoders that use the photosensitive element and an LED shining through the perforated disk. Is there a special term/category  for type of "camera-like" optical encoders used in mice?

If you don't mind a slight redesign, almost all HP vintage inkjet printers contain a film strip as wide as the carriage and, likely, a quadrature optical pickup. This allows the printer to know where to place dots on the paper.

"Is there a special term/category for type of "camera-like" optical encoders", not sure. it's just a low resolution camera. Certainly less than 100 pixels. You sure you are looking at the best tech for your project? Most wood working equipment use linear electronic capacitive, inductive or magnetic sensors.

This is the same as a rotary quadrature encoder except you want a reflective rather than transmissive geometry.

I have read the term "optical flow" decoder to describe the kind of sensor an optical mouse uses. Move prediction systems in movie players run a related task.

can you change to stripes or are the checkers required?

@JasenСлаваУкраїні checkers are just for the illustration purposes. the surface is actually just matte steel (silvery)

is there a risk of dust? rust?   what precision and repeatability are wanted? required?

@JasenСлаваУкраїні  Dust is a risk. Rust is not. Precision is not too critical and can be plus-minus 20mm

Range of expected motion would be good to know too. As a Sharp optical distance sensor is not a viable solution with a +/- 20mm allowed error. But different Sharp optical distance sensors have different range and granularity specifications (these are often found in copying machines to sens paper and on low cost robots to sense distance).

@st2000 The bogie is on a 10m long track. So it will move  from 0 to 10m. However, just as the images show, the distance from the sensor to the rail will remain constant (10mm). The sensor must detect the relative motion of scanned surface i.e like an optical mouse does.

Sorry, I meant to say "...distance sensor is now a viable solution...". The Sharp distance sensors are not like optical mice. You would aim the sensor at a fixed surface and through parallax they would output and analog voltage proportional to the distance. But 10m may be a bit too long for these sensors.
